# Is there a USB-based external display to add to Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: usb, ubuntu-10.04, display

I am looking to add a supplemental display to a Ubuntu 10.04 box. This is a smaller display, like a small notepad. Ultimately, I would like to run some status software, such as email checking, or network status. I read about many such displays, on ThinkGeek, but I could not figure ou twhether this will work under Linux.

Merci :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lilliput and the Mimo both use a [DisplayLink](http://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/) chipset.